# Allowing two classes to share variables and methods

Tags: java, oop, organization

So I'm trying to keep my program more organized. To do this I have on file containing my methods and the other has the event listeners and variables. The second file needs to use methods from the first file to change variables and whatnot. The first needs to use variables from the second to run properly. Basically:

```
public class Controls extends javax.swing.Jfarme{
   int turns = 0;
   int stuff = btnSet(jButton1);
}

public class GamePlay{
   public int btnSet(javax.swing.JButton btn){
   //do stuff using turn
   turn++;
   }
}
```

Do this make sense? How can I let these two share?
EDIT: I want two classes to keep it better organized. I made TicTacToe, then TicTacTwo, and now TicTacCube. It is simply getting a bit messy (I now have 243 JButtons to keep track of). I just want to split my methods from the code being executed to be pretty.

Comment: Why do you need 2 classes in the first place?

Comment: your class should contain all the variables, methods it needs to run. If both classes you create need to share methods, they should probably extend a super class that has those methods.

Comment: Describe the relationship between these two classes.  What does `GamePlay` mean to `Controls`, and vice-versa?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### For it to work with your current design:

1. To use `btnset()` function from the `Controls` class, import the `GamePlay` class into the `Controls` class, then instantiate a `GamePlay` class object to access its `btnset()` function.
   ex. `GamePlay gameplay = new GamePlay();`
   `gameplay.btnset();`
2. To use the `turns` variable in the `GamePlay` class, import the `Controls` class into the `GamePlay` class, then instantiate a `Controls` class object to access its `turns` variable.
   ex.
   `Controls controls = new Controls();`
   `controls.turns++;`

Alternatively you could make the method or variable static so you don't need to instantiate an object first.  If the method/variable were static you could just call `GamePlay.btnset();` or `Controls.turns++;`

Comment: Ah yes this should work, I forgot this was a thing. I'll try it out.

Answer (score 1):

*Disclaimer: of course, there are many ways to design the classes architecture of an application, so the following is just one way (but not the worst) to do it.*

My impression is that you haven't adopted the concept of object-oriented design and programming.

If you describe the (gaming?) application to someone else, you'll surely use a lot of nouns and verbs. A rule of thumb is to make classes out of the nouns, and methods out of the verbs. I guess that the words "Controls" (especially as it's plural) and "GamePlay" won't be the most prominent ones in your description, so don't start there. Instead I'd expect nouns like "Player", "Board", or "Figure", and verbs like "move", "collect", "shoot" or whatever your game is about. For the verbs, becoming methods, you have to decide in which class they belong, and you do this mainly by answering the question who or what is the subject of the sentence, so e.g. `move()` should become a method of `Figure`, as it isn't the board or the player moving, but the figure on the board.

When further designing the classes, concentrate on the inner workings (the "business logic") of the entities, and not the user interface - that should be kept in distinct classes.

So, a decent design of such an application might hava a `GamePlay` class with the top-level workflow of the application, but `GamePlay` shouldn't have any user interface (javax.swing.*) elements in it. The user interface (maybe something like your `Controls` class) should communicate with `GamePlay` and its companions only by calling some of their methods, not by reading fields.

P.S. Regarding questions on StackOverflow: it's preferred to copy parts of real code into questions, so you avoid typos like `Jfarme` instead of `JFrame`.

Comment: I am fully aware I'm still learning, but the basic concepts of naming and the stuff like that is not hard for me, I just threw this little piece together in a minute because I hadn't written really any code yet. In this case the btnSet needs to use a JBtn to set text.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, there are effectively two ways you can do this: statically, or using objects (java is an object-oriented language after all)

### Statically

A static approach to this effectively means that all variables and methods belong to the *classes* themselves. This would require putting the keyword `static` before all variables in the Controls class and all methods in the GamePlay class. These would all then be accessed by `ClassName.variable` or `ClassName.method()` e.g. `Controls.turns` or `GamePlay.btnSet(btn)`

### Using Objects

This approach means that new *instances* of your classes are created, each of which hold their own instance variables and methods, which would be accessed using `instance_name.variable` or `instance_name.method()`. This would involve creating instances of the classes, e.g. `Controls controls_instance = new Controls()` or `GamePlay gameplay_instance = new GamePlay()`, and then referencing their attributes, e.g. `controls_instance.turns` or `gameplay_instance.setBtn(btn)`

Comment: Just an FYI - if you don't understand the question being posed, you can leave a comment on the question asking for clarification.

Comment: @Makoto Thanks, I'll keep that in mind in future when answering questions :)